# AFNewtorking loading images from Amazon S3

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3, afnetworking

We were using AFNetworking only to load images like this:

```
[thumbnailImage setImageWithURL:_item.thumbnailUrl];
```

and it worked fine.  But now we've pulled in the rest of the project it has stopped working.  It was just showing the background color.  So I tried using this and it loads the placeholder but never loads the image.

```
UIImage* placeholder = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];
[thumbnailImage setImageWithURL:_item.thumbnailUrl placeholderImage:placeholder];
```

I thought I might be able to see what the problem was so I tried:

```
NSURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_item.thumbnailUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:30];

[thumbnailImage setImageWithURLRequest:urlRequest placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
{
    NSLog(@"Loaded Image");
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to load Image");
}];
```

and it seems that it's not getting the return type that it's expecting.  It says `Expected content type image/png, got binary/octet-stream`  I'm pulling the image from Amazon S3 so I don't know if I have control over the type.

Comment: Which AFNetworking version? It's an easy fix but the available solutions depend on which version you're using.

Comment: I'm using 1.0.  I figured out a fix by patching the call to `acceptableContentTypes`.

Comment: Probably best to the correct Content-type on your images on S3 if possible.

Comment: @CaseyB I just hit the exact same problem! I can't change the image content-type itself on S3. How did you manage to make it work in the end? Where did you change the acceptableContentTypes?

Comment: I'll post an answer with the code.

Comment: @CaseyB I'm running into the same problem with AFNetworking (the latest version 2.2.1) trying to pull an image from Amazon S3. I get AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: binary/octet-stream" But I know it's an image. Let me know if you know a solution to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to change the data type so I overrode the `acceptableContentTypes` method in AFNetworking by adding the following files to my project.

**AFImageRequestOperation+OctetMIMEType.h**

```
//
//  AFImageRequestOperation+OctetMIMEType.h
//  iQ.fileShare
//
//  Created by Poole, Patrick on 4/25/13.
//
//

#import "AFImageRequestOperation.h"

@interface AFImageRequestOperation (OctetMIMEType)

@end
```

**AFImageRequestOperation+OctetMIMEType.m**

```
//
//  AFImageRequestOperation+OctetMIMEType.m
//  iQ.fileShare
//
//  Created by Poole, Patrick on 4/25/13.
//
//

#import "AFImageRequestOperation+OctetMIMEType.h"

@implementation AFImageRequestOperation (OctetMIMEType)
+ (NSSet *)acceptableContentTypes {
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"binary/octet-stream",@"image/tiff", @"image/jpeg", @"image/gif", @"image/png", @"image/ico", @"image/x-icon" @"image/bmp", @"image/x-bmp", @"image/x-xbitmap", @"image/x-win-bitmap", nil];
}
@end
```

Comment: You appear to be overriding a method with a category, while this normally works, Apple says this behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking provides a method to add acceptable content types in 1.3.3, I'm not sure what other versions support this

```
[AFImageRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"binary/octet-stream", nil]];
```